# goclipse error "resource doesn't have a corresponding go package"

Tags: eclipse, go, path, goclipse, gopath

I check in questions database and find this: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34775953/golang-on-eclipse-resource-doesnt-have-a-corresponding-go-package-on-mac) but problem doesn't solve.

My pc have windows 10 and eclipse Neon.3 Release (4.6.3), goclipse is installed, my set for Go are:

- Go installation: `C:\Go`
- Eclipse GOPATH: `C:\Go\workspace`

tools path are:

- gocode: `C:\Go\bin\bin\gocode.exe`
- guru: `C:\Go\bin\bin\guru.exe`
- godef: `C:\Go\bin\bin\godef.exe`

but I think tools work.

I search for this by 3 days. thank for your help.

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Answer (score 0):

You should write the code inside folder which present inside src folder, ie the src folder shouldn't contain any *.go files it can contain folder which contains go files.

Here is an example,

```
> New_Project/
├── bin
│   └── test.exe
├── pkg
│   └── windows_amd64
└── src
    ├── strlocal
    │   └── file1.go
    └── test
        └── main.go
```